# Adjust CSS image masks on :hover in a carousel

Tags: javascript, html, css

Much easier to explain with an image (see below).
https://www.dropbox.com/s/2a19vv7pooop0r3/stack.jpg

I'd like to make an interactive carousel by displaying 4 images.
Each image takes up 25% of space horizontally, but on rollover, expands to show the majority of the image. None of the images should translate in any way, just have their masks adjusted.

Reason:
I've got 4 renders of a 3D model (wireframe, solid, textured, rendered).
I'd like to be able to see more/less of each one by hovering over them.

Edit:
Video explains it perfectly:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/g3mq15mlf560q68/example.mov

Comment: Do you need to handle the case of more than 4 images? Could you also explain what "just have their masks adjusted" means?

Comment: Thanks @cgatian. Just 4 images! Each of the four images should be aligned identically, and never move left/right/up/down. What I mean by "just have their masks adjusted" is that hovering over a image causes you to see more of it, and less of the other three.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EDIT http://jsfiddle.net/xus5zx6s/3/

Sorry it took so long. The case statement could be improved logically but it works. I had a slight error in calculating the border in version 2 so use version 3.

EDIT: http://jsfiddle.net/xus5zx6s/5/

I want to STRESS this code could be cleaned up in a much more programmatic way, but it functions as you wish.

```
`$('#contain div').click(function(){
var id = $(this).data('id');
$('#contain div').removeClass('active');
$(this).addClass('active');
$("#contain div:not('.active')").animate({'width':'10%'}); 
$(this).animate({'width':'70%'});
switch(id){
    case 1:
        $('#img2 img').animate({'left':'-672px'});
        $('#img3 img').animate({'left':'-768px'});
        $('#img4 img').animate({'left':'-864px'});
        break;
    case 2:
        $('#img2 img').animate({'left':'-96px'});
        $('#img3 img').animate({'left':'-768px'});
        $('#img4 img').animate({'left':'-864px'});
        break;
    case 3:
        $('#img2 img').animate({'left':'-96px'});
        $('#img3 img').animate({'left':'-192px'});
        $('#img4 img').animate({'left':'-864px'});
        break;
    case 4:
        $('#img2 img').animate({'left':'-96px'});
        $('#img3 img').animate({'left':'-192px'});
        $('#img4 img').animate({'left':'-288px'});
        break;
}
```

});`

Comment: Great! How could I add easing in-out transition to the images on hover? I'd like a boarder either side of the images too (like you have) but this causes a slight offset between the images.

Comment: If you want to keep the border, then adjust the case statments where the images get adjusted by the border thickness (in my example 1px). I'd have to play with it to see if you need to increase them or decrease all the numbers. I think decrease. Easing can be accomplished by changing the `css` to `animate` basically. Lookup the jQuery documentation. I'll try to tweak if I have time.

Comment: I've updated a bit here real fast. Got the first few boxes tweaked right. http://jsfiddle.net/qv6wga6L/6/ Honestly a plugin, if one exists would be better, which is why I upvoted @cgatian's post below. You could get custom code to work, but a plugin most likely already figureed this out.

Comment: The annoying thing is I'm sure i've seen this design of carousel on a webpage before, I just can't seam to find where. I've looked through many of the example carousels on the web, but they all move the images in some way. If it involves at lot of code beyond HTML/CSS It's kind of beyond my scope at the moment. I've updated my original question with a video example.

Comment: I know what you want. I mean my code get's you most of the way. Just needs some tweaking. I'd have to sit down and really hammer it out as there would be some pretty smart JS involved to get it working right.

Comment: Here it is without images. I'll try to get the images added: http://jsfiddle.net/xus5zx6s/1/

Comment: Awesome! Can it return to 25%, 25%, 25%, 25% (it's default) when not being hovered or used?

Comment: Perfect! That works really well. I've gone ahead and improved in in php (which I'm a little better at) and made it easy to adjust things like number of items, percentage when inactive, width/height etc.. take a look. Also, is it possible to fix jittering around the far right edge? It's more visible when I increase the item count, although I'll probably just use 2-5 items. Thanks for your help! https://www.dropbox.com/s/1jkbchl9q9k177c/Leeish.php

Comment: I saw jittering sometimes too. But not in all browsers. You might try using a different engine to run the animations to see if it makes a difference like velocity.js: http://julian.com/research/velocity/. Also I noticed if you hover quickly over multiple from off the area it drops the right one down for a moment. Might wrap the whole thing in a fixed height div with overflow hidden so it doesn't mess up your page flow.

Answer (score 1):

Implemented what I think you're looking for using a flexbox.  Im sure you might need to tweak it a bit, but it might be what you're looking for.

http://jsbin.com/wocolukiyido

**Editable:**
http://jsbin.com/wocolukiyido/1/edit?css,output

**HTML:**

```
  <div class='border'>
    <div class='grid'>
      <div class='img1'></div>
      <div class='img2'></div>
      <div class='img3'></div>
      <div class='img4'></div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.border {
    border: 1px solid black;
    width: 960px;
}

.grid {
    display: flex;
    -ms-flex-wrap: nowrap;
    flex-wrap: nowrap;
}

.grid:hover > div {
    width: 5%;
}

.grid > div:hover {
    width: 90%;
}

.grid > div {
    height: 100px;
    width: 25%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

.img1 {
    background-image: url('http://fillmurray.com/960/100');
}

.img2 {
    background-image: url('http://fillmurray.com/960/101');
}

.img3 {
    background-image: url('http://fillmurray.com/960/102');
}

.img4 {
    background-image: url('http://fillmurray.com/960/103');
}
```

Comment: Sorry I had some code not working there. I forgot to modify .grid:hover .item . It should be .grid:hover > div

Comment: Yes...nearly! In your example, the images are stacked vertically, I'd like them to be horizontally next to each other, and on rollover eat into the space of it's neighbours. Also, i'm not sure if this is deliberate or not but 75% of .grid in your example is blank! Thanks again.

Comment: I added some vendor specifics, should would great in Chrome

Comment: Running it in Chrome gives very different results to Safari. In Safari, the images don't move (great!) but they're stacked vertically (see attached). In Chrome they're horizontal and look great, but the 2nd, 3rd and forth images move as they're rolled over. This picture shows the top image selected in Safari. https://www.dropbox.com/s/iziiyag6rkm7b11/himesakonipo.png

Comment: Thanks for that Joe, taking a look.

Comment: Updated again. If you're still getting issues with Safari could you post the version and if it's on Win/Mac?

Comment: Version wocolukiyido is exactly the same as himesakonipo, but on rollover the images snap to position. Tested on OSX Chrome (latest) and Safari (latest).

Comment: Are you testing on a Mac or Windows?

Comment: I dont have a Mac available and the windows version of Safari is quite dated (latest is 7 windows version is 5). The features, mainly flexbox, should be available in all browsers. http://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox

Comment: Tested on many browsers. https://www.dropbox.com/s/7fl4bwhtfgzyihf/wocolukiyido.jpg Flexbox seams to be the nicest solution but keeping the images static is still an issue.

Comment: Added an example video in the question.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a html/css3 method that simulates what you want.  Percent size is reduced a bit because of the spacing between divs, but should get the point across.

http://jsfiddle.net/biz79/51625mom/

HTML

```
<div id='container'>
<div><img src="https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/2542034/colorPicks/pink.png"></div>
<div><img src="https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/2542034/colorPicks/pink.png"></div>
<div><img src="https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/2542034/colorPicks/pink.png"></div>
<div><img src="https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/2542034/colorPicks/pink.png"></div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
* {
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
  transition: width 200ms ease-in-out;
  /* edit the time 200ms to change transition speed */
}

#container {
    width:960px;    
}

#container div {
    width:24%;
    height:200px;
    display:inline-block;
    overflow:hidden;
}

#container:hover div {
    width:10%;   
}

#container div:hover {
    width:68%;   
}
```

Comment: You can't quite see with this example, but when I replace the nth-child's colours with background images, the images move on each rollover.

Comment: I changed the background colors to img tags, set a src and overflow:hidden.  You can adjust the transition time in the css, but it looks like at least a few ms are needed to handle the state between 25% all images and the split second that you hover over an image on the far right side.  I can play around with it later if you like this solution.

Comment: Can you update your code above with the changes? I can't seam to keep them still! thanks.